# Converting vertical bar separated .txt file into dictionary

Tags: python

The original format is a txt file in the format of:

las vegas,nv|36.17497|-115.13722

The txt contains about 70 rows in the same format

The target dictionary format should be {“city name”:[latitude, longitude]}

Thanks for one of the answer but still get stuck:

```
with open("cities.txt") as f:
    txt = f.read()
lines = txt.split('\n')
my_dict = dict()
for line in lines:
    city,lat,lng = txt.split('|')
    my_dict[city] = [lat,lng]
```

It shows: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3), what should I modify next?

I'll paste the format of txt file as below:

```
las vegas,nv|36.17497|-115.13722
homestead,pa|40.4059|-79.91199
streetsboro,oh|41.23922|-81.34594
```

Comment: What did you try? Show us your code and improve your question (typo, brackets) because it's a mess. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open(my_file.txt) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    my_dict = dict()
    for line in lines:
        city,lat,lng = line.split('|')
        my_dict[city] = [lat,lng]
```

Comment: I think this would be slightly better if you called readlines on the file object instead of reading the whole thing into memory first.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the original txt file contains about 70 rows, the formats are all like the first row. In python the result shows that "too many values to unpack (expected 3)" what should I modify next? Thanks

Comment: (anyway how can you expect to develop as a developer if u only rely on others to solve your coding experience... I suggest you to learn how to debug your code or get some tutorial on how to work with python)

Comment: I have pasted the content in the question part, there is a restriction for the length so only part of the txt content can be shown

Comment: hi.. u can look now for working solution, i misstyped and instead of writing `line.split()` i used `txt`

Comment: It works, thank you very much....I'm a freshman from other field and just start to learn programming. I'll follow your advice and learn some basics

Answer (score 1):

In the line before the last line of your code, you use `txt`, which should be `line` :)